How does this circuit generate a PWM output, and how do the components interact to create the waveform?

This circuit is taken from the Electronics Communication modulation and transmission book by Schoenbeck, Chapter 2.Page number is 52.Ideal op amp 741  It is designed to generate a PWM (Pulse Width Modulated) signal and includes the following components:

A 2 kHz square wave generator as the primary input.
An RC network consisting of a 10 kΩ resistor and a 100 nF capacitor, connected to the square wave generator, producing a triangular waveform.
A 100 Hz sinusoidal wave source connected to a 10 kΩ resistor.

1. RC Network and Triangular Wave Generation

How does the RC network convert the square wave into a triangular waveform?
Why does the capacitor create a smooth ramp instead of just following the square wave directly?
How do the resistor and capacitor values (10 kΩ, 100 nF) affect the resulting triangular waveform (e.g., its amplitude, frequency, or phase shift)?


2. Role of the First Op-Amp

What is the purpose of the first op-amp in this circuit?
What mode is the first op-amp operating in (e.g., buffer, integrator, amplifier)?
What does the first op-amp output look like, and how does it process the triangular wave?
Why is this step necessary before the second op-amp?


3. Inputs to the Second Op-Amp

How does the second op-amp receive its inputs? Specifically:

How does the triangular wave output from the first op-amp get used by the second op-amp?
How does the sinusoidal wave (100 Hz) interact with the second op-amp, and why is it used?


What parameters of the triangular wave (e.g., amplitude, frequency) and the sinusoidal wave affect the operation of the second op-amp?


4. Second Op-Amp and PWM Generation

How does the second op-amp compare the inputs (triangular wave and sinusoidal wave) to generate a PWM signal?
Based on what parameters (e.g., the relative voltages of the two inputs), does the second op-amp switch its output between high and low?
How is the duty cycle of the PWM signal determined? What relationship exists between the sinusoidal wave and the duty cycle?
Why is the second op-amp configured as a comparator, and what would change if its configuration were different?


5. General PWM Behavior

How does the final PWM signal encode the sinusoidal waveform?
What is the significance of using a triangular waveform instead of another shape (e.g., sine or square) for comparison with the sinusoidal wave?
Why is the sinusoidal wave frequency lower than the triangular wave frequency, and how does this impact the PWM output?

The circuit I designed in Falstad can be checked and investigated here:
https://tinyurl.com/23xgkg3z

You’ve seemed to have skipped some fundamental electronic principles. You’ve named the RC network so some research on resistor and capacitor theory will answer most of your questions. The classic pwm generator consists of a triangle wave source into a comparator with the other input being the voltage representing the required pulse width. The circuit you show does it slightly different but the net result is the same.

I agree with Kartman (comments section), most of your questions will be answered by understanding how the R-C network behaves in the circuit you posted.


RC Network and Triangular Wave Generation
How does the RC network convert the square wave into a triangular waveform?
Why does the capacitor create a smooth ramp instead of just following the square wave directly?
How do the resistor and capacitor values (10 kΩ, 100 nF) affect the resulting triangular waveform (e.g., its amplitude, frequency, or phase shift)?


I suggest looking at just the "ramp generator" section of your circuit, as per the image below (which I copied from your circuit and added some mark-ups).  Note that one side of R2 has been connected to GND - this is very important to understand, and is due to the first op-amp in your circuit.

The variable to watch here is the current in R2, which is directly related to the voltage on C2.  Ideally, this will be a triangle wave, but with some "distortion". The degree of distortion will be determined by how big the voltage on C2 gets compared to the voltage of V1.
Let's call voltage on C2 "V(C2)".  If V(C2) is kept to less than, say, 20% of the peak voltage of V1, then V(C2) will look like an almost perfect triangle wave, and your eye will find it hard to detect any distortion.  However, as the peak of V(C2) gets closer to the peak of V1, the straight lines of the triangle wave will start to bend.
I suggest investigating this circuit in detail, keep V1, R1 and R2 the same, but changing only C1.  You will start to see that the value of C2 has a distinct impact on V(C2), specifically:
a) its peak value of V(C2), and
b) the distortion its waveform.
When you understand this, you will be able to answer most of your other questions yourself.
